# Swift on Linux: -static-stdlib cannot find -lFoundation

Tags: linux, swift, foundation

I am trying to build a command line tool on linux that uses Foundation. 
But I run into an error, for that I can not find a solution:

```
swiftc -static-stdlib Sources/main.swift Sources/array.swift Sources/check.swift
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lFoundation
/tmp/main-3a78a1.o:/tmp/main-3a78a1.o:function main: error: undefined reference to '_TMV10Foundation12CharacterSet'
/tmp/main-3a78a1.o:/tmp/main-3a78a1.o:function main: error: undefined reference to '_TWPV10Foundation12CharacterSets10SetAlgebraS_'
/tmp/main-3a78a1.o:/tmp/main-3a78a1.o:function main: error: undefined reference to '_TFE10FoundationSS10componentsfT11separatedByVS_12CharacterSet_GSaSS_'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does somebody know how to build a swift project static?